# Access denied when trying to delete a page layout or master page

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, access-denied, page-layout

I'm getting:

> "This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages."

When I try to delete a master page or a page layout. All the pages that were made with those are now gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a sub folder in Sharepoint designer (SPD), move the master pages or page layouts that you want to delete in it, and then delete the sub folder.
Thanks to http://www.jamik.de/news.php?item.48